# Where is the list of names of pictos font icons in sencha touch 2.4

Tags: sencha-touch, senchatouch-2.4

In sencha touch documentation and forums, I could not find the list of names of 96 pictos font icons that I should pass in icon() mixin in order to import an icon. Like in following example:

@include icon('search');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full list of all those token you can find out, if you open touch distribution file 
*touch/resources/themes/stylesheets/sencha-touch/base/mixins/_Class.scss*,
line 393 (last distro), function **@function icon-character-for-name($name)**

Here is a reference to the pictos site: http://pictos.cc/classic/font

Comment: Thanks @olegtaranenko. I don't know why this information is missing from sencha touch API docs.

Answer (score 1):

For 2.4.2

Look for the @function icon-character-for-name($name)
here: 
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/source/_Class.scss2.html#Global_CSS-css_mixin-icon

Icons are at http://pictos.cc/font/

Remember to @include icon('icon name') in your scss;

Answer (score 0):

@olegtaranenko answer is pretty helpful for people.

If you want you can use this Gist I made.

Maybe you already know, but if you want to use a custom icon...

```
@include icon('name', 'a', 'icon-font-name');
```

https://gist.github.com/Trozdol/e1239391e06cce4fd767.js

Comment: Not just custom icon, It is also possible to include a pictos icon using that signature, for example: `@include icon('someanchor', 'a', 'pictos');` will include anchor icon with reference name as 'someanchor'. Thanks for the list @Trozdol

Comment: Re reading my post I realize I forgot to clarify that. Whoops